# Adding views to Stackview, but the subviews of the stackview overlap with each other

Tags: swift, for-loop, uistackview

I need to adding views to stackview by using "for in" loops. However,  the views in the stackview are overlap with each other.

addplantoPlanArray samply init a view and add it to the PlanArray, then using "for in" loop to add each view in that Array into the stackview.

here is the code:

```
    self.addPlantoPlanArray(IDText: "123123", Name: "abc", Participants: "abc", Duration: "abc", Price: "abc")
    self.addPlantoPlanArray(IDText: "14123123", Name: "123123", Participants: "123123", Duration: "123123", Price: "123123")
    for plan in PlanArray {
        stackview.addArrangedSubview(plan)
    }
    stackview.axis = .horizontal
    stackview.distribution = .fillEqually
    stackview.spacing = 274
    view.addSubview(stackview)
```

The result is that the second view is totally overlap on the first one.

The constrains for the stackview:

```
    view.addSubview(PlanStackView)
    PlanStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let stackviewTop = NSLayoutConstraint(item: PlanStackView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 380)
    let stackviewLeading = NSLayoutConstraint(item: PlanStackView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
    view.addConstraints([stackviewTop, stackviewLeading])
```

No constrains for the instance view, it is init with default frame. here is the init method for the instance class:

```
    init(PlanDefaultIDText: String, PlanNameText: String, PlanParticipantsText: String, PlanDurationText: String, PlanPriceText: String) {
    super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 264, height: 150))
```

Comment: Need help... This sucks me for two hours. adding views into the stackview individually is fine, but when using For in Loops, it sucks.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would need `274` points as spacing. That's code smell to me. What device are you using?

Comment: Can you also show us the constriants of the stackview itself. did you set the stackView's `translatesautoresizingmaskintoconstraints` to `false`? If that didn't work then we also need to see the constraints of the `plan` instance as well.

Comment: I update the constrains for the stackview, thanks. the 274 help to make it looks good, but does not help when adding a third view.

Comment: **1. Where is your stackView's trailing and bottom constraints?!** 2. It's not vital rather *cleaner* if your `init` method would just take 1 model that encapsulates all its Strings, so you wouldn't have to pass to it like this ie do `Struct Plan{ var defaultIDText: String; nameText: String, ParticipantsText: String; duration: String; prince: String}` and then instantiate your view with `init(plan: Plan){
self.plan = plan;
    super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 264, height: 150))
}`

Comment: Many Thanks I see what you mean.

Comment: Problem solved by changing the plan class  to  plan struct.

Comment: not sure how that solves a layout problem...